# How to store the value into the xslt variable returned from Javascript function?

Tags: 2013, javascript, xslt, item-styles

I have created a template in ItemStyle.xsl for CQWP.

I want to store the xsl variable value that is returned from javascript:

My template is:

```
<xsl:template name="DepartmentsTemplate" match="Row[@Style='DepartmentsTemplate']" mode="itemstyle">

<xsl:variable name="DisplayTitle">
        <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetTitle">
            <xsl:with-param name="Title" select="@Title"/>                                    
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>     
    <xsl:variable name="CurrSite"/> // I want this variable value to be assigned from javascript function return value.       

<a> <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(@Department,'|')" disable-output-escaping="yes"></xsl:value-of></a>  

 </xsl:template>
```

Javascript function is:

```
function getValue()
{
var url = location.protocol + "//" + location.host +  L_Menu_BaseUrl;   

var n= url.lastIndexOf("/");

var currSite = url.substring(n+1,url.length);

return currSite;

}
```

How do I accomplish this?

Javascript function is defined in another js file that is, it is not written in the ItemStyle.xsl

Answer (score 1):

Since XSLT transformation in SharePoint is invoked on the server side, there's no way to execute JavaScript code **before** XSLT transformation.

---

### How to pass the current Web Url in Content Query web part

I assume in your scenario the current site url should be passed into ItemStyle.xsl, there is another way how it could be accomplished.

Specify [ProjectProperty.SiteUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.projectproperty.property.aspx) via CQWP [ViewFieldsOverride](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.contentbyquerywebpart.viewfieldsoverride%28v=office.14%29.aspx) property,
where 
[ProjectProperty.Url](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.projectproperty.property.aspx) - Full URL of the current Web site

```
<property name="ViewFieldsOverride" type="string"><![CDATA[<ProjectProperty Name="Url" />]]></property>
```

After that `ProjectProperty.Url` could be used in `ItemStyle.xsl`:

```
<xsl:value-of select="@ProjectProperty.Url" /> <!-- returns a full URL of the current Web site -->
```

Answer (score 0):

If Curr site is a the current site URL you can check out the xsl server variables that SharePoint makes avaialable including URL and QUERY_STRING params. A link to the MSDN docs and a tutorial can be found below.

[Tutorial on using the server variables in XSLT webpart](http://sympmarc.com/2007/10/19/data-view-web-part-parameters-based-on-server-variables/)

[MSDN Documentation of XSL Server variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602.aspx)